# Searching a values in multiple txt files

Tags: python, multiple-columns

I am new to python coding. I need help in reading multiple .txt files.

I have around 50 .txt files each containing 30 columns.

I search a value in column 25 and getting corresponding value in column 1.

It should be for all the files in the directory.

Thanks in advance.

Current Code is :

```
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file_list = glob.glob('*.txt')
for file_path in data:
   for i in range(250,300,50):
    First_start_pcls=5500 # rows
    First_end_pcls=6000 #rows
for d in file_list:
    a_s=(d[First_start_pcls:First_end_pcl,1])
    b_s=(d[First_start_pcls:First_end_pcl,25])
```

However, I am struck from here.

I need to know the value like `x>-72 & X<-73`. between `5500:6000` rows 
and then print columns 1 (a), 25 (v)

the txt file looks like this.

```
0 0.100002 0.100005 0.1 750 0 0.15 150 0 0 0.09999 5000 10 -1.79126e-06 -9.70263e-10 0.285642 -0.0212535 0 0 1.0251 0.00229463 0.00061384 -1.39956e-06 0 0.00168796 -79.2124 0.000385773 0.00109869 0 0 180
1 0.100375 0.100805 0.100233 750.028 3.25521e-06 0.149993 150 8.43446e-11 3.86358e-14 0.099039 5000 10 -26.1624 -0.201879 0.477011 0.142304 0 -0.00478525 4.66682e-10 0.489863 0.0755384 7.18662e-05 0.000464599 0.0328732 38.385 0.000387414 0.0010954 0 0 180.043
2 0.100732 0.102105 0.105489 750.106 2.79018e-06 0.149986 150 9.00251e-10 8.79657e-13 0.0981785 5000 10 -0.00916317 -0.193042 0.477412 0.150787 0 -0.0620785 3.08304e-10 1.92367 0.28177 0.000263186 0.00183184 0.0332253 39.4411 0.000388996 0.00109228 0 0 180.085
3 0.101075 0.103434 0.1177 750.224 6.97545e-06 0.149979 150 3.1313e-09 4.85265e-12 0.0973999 5000 10 -3.72894e-06 -0.21107 0.476546 0.148985 0 -0.0820207 7.45346e-10 2.27915 0.375781 0.000542299 0.00339836 0.0324755 36.5965 0.000390519 0.00108931 0 0 180.126
4 0.101405 0.104825 0.132947 750.376 1.95313e-05 0.149972 150 7.05902e-09 1.5288e-11 0.0966955 4999.99 10 -1.55684e-09 -0.230125 0.475581 0.146907 0 -0.104142 1.89863e-09 2.28998 0.409257 0.000881221 0.00511384 0.0316808 33.5859 0.000391987 0.00108649 0 0 180.166
5 0.101722 0.106308 0.14629 750.554 4.13876e-05 0.149965 150 1.27143e-08 3.58097e-11 0.0960581 4999.99 10 -6.68377e-13 -0.248602 0.474587 0.145348 0 -0.136107 4.71837e-09 2.19423 0.41199 0.00125702 0.00695662 0.0309066 30.6545 0.0003934 0.00108381 0 0 180.205
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. what have you tried? we do not provide code here. we help fixing problems

Comment: Hi Gio, thanks for answering. I have added my current code.

Comment: can you use pandas?

Comment: I can use but not very familiar. Python is new to me.

Comment: can you show a sample of the input file? does the code work up to the point you wrote?

Comment: With this code, I can get the one column value not corresponding column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#change this if you have a header and use the proper separator according to your text file
df= pd.read_csv('inputfile.txt', sep=" ", header=None) 

#this if you actually have a column named 'x', for which you want to check if the values are between 73 and 74.
df=df[df['x'].between(73,74)].loc[5499:5999] 
#if your columns are unnamed and you know which column you want to check (say the second column, which has index 1)
df=df[df[:,1].between(73,74)].loc[5499:5999] 

print(df.iloc[:,0])
print(df.iloc[:,24])
```

### Edit

Given OP comment

```
import glob 
import os 
import numpy as np 
import csv 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
dff = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in glob.iglob("*.txt"): 
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=" ", header=None) 
    df=df[df[25].between(-73,-72)].loc[7999:9999]   
    dff=dff.append([df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,4]])
    print(df.iloc[:][0]) 
    print(df.iloc[:][25])
```

Comment: Thanks Gio. It worked for one file. Let me do it for multiple files. Thanks again

Comment: Now, I am facing problems for multiple txt files.   import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dff=[]
files = glob.glob("*.txt")
for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(files, sep=" ", header=None)
    df=[df[25].between(-73,-72)].loc[7999:9999]
    dff=dff.append(df.iloc[:][0],df.iloc[:][25])
print(df.iloc[:][0])
print(df.iloc[:][25])

Comment: @vika1989 see updated answer. I think you are looping the wrong element. You should create the dataframe from `filename`, not from `files`

Comment: Looped on the files .. Now the error is 
'list' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: @vika1989 how does `files` look? what is the type of the file and what's the content?

Comment: "files" is for a directory as a250.txt 255.txt. content is similar as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @vika1989 the problem is your `dff`. why do you create that list and append to it?

Comment: So basically, I want to get a value from all the files.

Like from a200: 245
                a250: 249
and then save it an array or list

Comment: @vika1989 check the updated answer. You can transpose your dataframe with df.T. If you know the columns name you can create the empty dataset with columns name and avoid having to transpose after

Comment: Still the same error 
df=[df[25].between(-74,-72)].loc[7999:9999]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: @vika1989 fixed

Comment: Its perfect now.. Thank you very much.. You saved a lot of my time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a txt file and write on each line the text file you want to open using the program :
e.g.

```
test.txt
dics.txt
fruit.txt
code.txt
...
```

Then you should create a for loop to choose every filename from the txt file you created and read it:
e.g.

```
files = open("filenames.txt","r")
for file in files:
    x = open(file,"r").read()
    print(x)
```

**I wish that could help you.**